# Is there any way to get authorization code programatically?

Tags: azure, active-directory

I need to integrate my app with an application that needs to get an Azure AD access token. I can get MSAL token to call the APIs, but I want to get the Authorization token programmatically.
Is there any way I can get the authorization access token without user interaction?
I have the secret key, and I've tried the approach below. But it's an access token, not authorization token:

```
            string ClientID = "client_it";

            string ClientSecret = "secret";
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(ClientID, ClientSecret);

            string TenantID = "tenantId";
            
            string endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TenantID;



            ClientCredential credent = new ClientCredential(ClientID, ClientSecret);

            var context = new AuthenticationContext(endpoint);
            var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://localhost", credent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to get an Authorization code, User Interaction is required.

I tried the below code to get the authorization URL and then fetched the authorization code in C# like below:-

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

string tenantId = "xxxxxxxxx-7f45-4ce4-99ed-af9038592395";
string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb";
string redirectUri = "https://jwt.ms";
string scopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read";


string authorizationRequest = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&scope={scopes}";

Console.WriteLine("Navigate to the following URL in a web browser and sign in:");
Console.WriteLine(authorizationRequest);
Console.WriteLine("After signing in, enter the authorization code from the response URL:");
string authorizationCode = Console.ReadLine();
```

Got below URL to fetch the Authorization code:-

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-7f45-4ce4-99ed-af9038592395/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
```

Output :-

[image]

I entered the above URL in the browser and got authorization code like below:-

```http
https://jwt.ms/?code=0.xxxxxxxxxxx_5EyZ7a-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.AgABAAIAAAD--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_wUA9P9KxUwYv7HLv9iErJL_sAZdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFEJ0uAYJXhu7dP87C4OSk0vo4AlEUzPDPvLZHIDLzclaJsNnNDiSLiHyWNd48PUy_GgTqO0WKg81hoIViAJa5UcK_AWaVrBzQwjv0EYl9ZsSNLr6YPSMQxhl3qNPNUIsflPJscS8NM-oiLMpR87zLhC6iEdQJLZQRrPxtFgaMm92AIl6B-U6hY9BngAJGh-5Dj94V-PIHGWtcoQFJTzgRc_Vg_syqkbjnbXFs2pP-CZcBUmYR8Mbog41ogQwGgxZqi9LGBucqG6TNgbFZHen5J6V_TgmQECcDb3FkWxNE53HWQkQc-BLufIj7-1CdhXogVq_8_zCbwHd6XEzp6gLWql8YSY3X0pLJWCB3rrcXlxtowBqpGslStho0y-UvlxPjeQuePz5i4y6r796Vle_-ASS8Nsh1JJuTLVGnGSk1BcDh3Q_8qdvBXsg9gnkQO6r8cxNOalav4EQjEkxVU1MWGALFZFfMfneW5ZnL3vitSitIr7SFNSk6MiLFvk9Y62gDLI7BssUI6IYucbjPvLIS292HiIloK-lR0IH3f_QUgAKnJhSbUof3aQG1ivENOBlnCV8DNifQf3JqmqfGPBN45Kd3HV5ZqH_wEOQC_RBQbPHzX-K0ynEE77edCiX5-1ffrF2McdY7MJqzQq1i00tX2zASKkyFC-J5gdT0HOGLY-aNURyd2AMPb75JoOzZiT0gMRIDTImpvf3Cm1CVv3fZkrdpugebKr7pPfVV9YCBwmzNnJxjDauDZ19gxQwk6gcbaJZ-4bVvUJYVD9pfMvv_kE-fw-_5YnKfd7KzGv5W3I2V5YLSetH2Ajw5V1OktiJfssSs6GjTgk3l6tajn_YOLsNyIPHC6nbDxAex-Cds1oy4yz2MxTUpaGqBsaXBsp-CBR37s_oSc_sGfZuhuSR1ftLkopEdPai8F2DQPlQBVETmLPqHxWyqv3AC6JlhCpZN1CdomNyLLODwqCs4mTxpCe7Eyjm4_8G-dM0KPgHYsBFTgTOQvrbnU2H3mEWXyA1Fx_Y060_pnO3ul5RElxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwKfuqyDC3EhKOhJszPjLvMwfXo2PYt6t2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&session_state=43b59ee-39c2-4868-b2c5-xxxxxxxxxxx#
```

[image]

Now, You can use this Authorization code to fetch your access token with below code: -

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


string tenantId = "tenantId";
string clientId = "clientId";
string clientSecret = "clientSecret";
string redirectUri = "http://localhost:8000" or "https://jwt.ms";
string authorizationCode = "authorizationCode";

string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestBody = $"client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&client_secret={clientSecret}&code={authorizationCode}&grant_type=authorization_code";

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenEndpoint);
    request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // parse the response content to extract the access token
}
```